# Integreal around a unit circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I know that when $m \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ 0 \}$,
we have
$$
\int_0^1 e^{2 \pi i m \beta} \ d \beta = 0.
$$
I was wondering if there is a simple formula for the following similar integral, when $m \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ 0 \}$ and $j \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\int_0^1 \beta^j e^{2 \pi i m \beta} \ d \beta?
$$
I am not really sure what to do. I would greatly appreciate any help
on this matter.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I_j=\int_0^1 \beta^j e^{2\pi im\beta}$.

Now use integration by parts: let $u=\beta^j$ and $v^\prime=e^{2\pi im\beta}$ then $\int uv^\prime = uv - \int u^\prime v$ which will give you an integrand of the form $\beta^{j-1}e^{2\pi im\beta}$. So you can write $I_j$ as a function of $I_{j-1}$. And you know what $I_0$ is, so you can solve it recursively.